# Trying to get a loop running concurrently with web.py

Tags: python

At this stage in my little project, I want to get web.py to display some information retrived from some sensors attached to my Raspberry Pi. I want the information to get retrieved regularly, so I put a loop at the bottom of my code that refreshes the sensors using my library, sticks the readings in a dict and sleeps for 10 seconds.

```
while True:
    onewiretemp.refreshSensor()
    temperatures = onewiretemp.sensorTemp
    time.sleep(10)
```

Unfortunately, the side effect of this is that when I run my program and try loading a page, my loop runs and the page never loads. I also have to manually kill the process to stop it. I assume this is because the loop is running indefinitely.

The rest of my code is basically the tutorial and some templating stuff from the web.py website. That part works when I disable the loop and manually add in the data formatted the same as the output from my onewiretemp module.

Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't break everything?

Comment: If you're only keeping the latest temperature around, and you're not going to be hitting this server from lots of different clients dozens of times/second… is there even a good reason to check every 10 seconds? Why not just check on each request?

Comment: Eventually I was hoping to collect the values and graph them over time. The short duration between checks was mostly for debugging purposes, I was having some issues with my wiring where the CRC would fail, so I wanted it to be tested a bunch of times. When I finish my project, I'll probably have it check every 10-30 minutes.

Comment: OK, that's reasonable. And tdelaney's answer will work just as well if, say, `temperatures` is a list of multiple values: in the polling thread, grab the lock and `append` to the list; in the web.py thread, grab the lock, copy the list to something you can return, and clear out the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the sensor poll loop in a separate thread. Protect temperatures with a lock when you read or write it. Your main web.py script can grab the lock and get the latest data.